# How to draw a "Line with Markers" graph like this?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

Please view this image (focus to red around area):

[image]

Comment: I see you have many questions about charts. I suggest you browse around [Jon Peltier's website](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/).Iit contains many useful tips on how to make and format charts just the way you want.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot get it to work with the letters, but I can get it to work with numbers (`=CODE(A1)-CODE("a")+1`):

[image: Scatter]

**UPDATE** after reading Jean-François's answer (but on another computer):

- Added a second series just for the custom labels
- Show data labels for the new series
- Explicitly set the Y axis minimum at 0
- Deleted the original X axis labels
- Deleted the legend entry of the second series

[image: Scatter2]

A few more steps and we're there:

- multiplied the X axis values by 10, to adjust granularity for positioning stuff
- subtracted 5 for series1 values, to get the data in the middle between major tick marks
- played with series2 values, to get the labels also in the middle between major tick marks

[image: Scatter3]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier way.

Set up the data like this:

[image: Data for chart with letter axis labels]

Select the first two columns (blue) and insert a column chart (zero value columns do not appear):
[image: Column Chart]

Select and copy third and fourth columns (red), select the chart, Paste Special as new series, check first column and first row boxes (it's added as another column):
[image: Column chart with XY data as another column]

Right click new column series, choose Change Series Chart Type, and select the XY with Lines style:
[image: Column and XY Chart]

Right click XY series, choose Format Data Series, change to Primary Axis:
[image: Finished XY chart with letter X axis labels]

Comment: Verified it, and it is not only easier but also much better!